# Add Text to a TextField Inside A MovieClip AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have been working on a project in Adobe Flash Pro CS5 and I am trying to add text to a textbox inside of a movieclip. I then want to add this movie clip to a scrollpane. I have this:
The instance names are 
scrollpane = scroller
movieclip = achievements
textbox = progress1 (I need to do this for 10 different text boxes all in the same movieclip)

```
import flash.text.TextField
achievements.progress1.text = "16";
scroller.source = achievements
```

When I run this I get the Error 1119: Access of possibly undefined property progress1 through a reference with static type Class.

I made the movieclip on  the stage and exported it for actionscript. I added the text boxes to this and game them all instance names. I Don't know what is wrong and really need some help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you apparently named your class "achievements" since as3 is saying the "progress1" property doesn't exist on the class itself.  Of course you will want to size and move the components as you see fit, but here is a basic idea for the class and it's usage:

```
package {

      public class Achievements extends MovieClip {

           public var progress1:TextField = new TextField();
           public var progress2:TextField = new TextField();
           public var progress3:TextField = new TextField();

           public function Achievements(){
                addChild(progress1);
                addChild(progress2);
                addChild(progress3);
           }
      }
 }

 //Then in your main code:

 var achievements:Achievements = new Achievements();
 addChild(achievements);


 //Then to set the text
 achievements.progress1.text = "it's alive!!!";
```

Comment: Thanks if I have to do this for lots of text boxes how would I do that. their instance names would be progress1, progress2, progress3 and so on. Also, does this work with a scrollpane?

Comment: edited the example to show you how to add more text field instances to it.  And yes they will work with ScrollPane

Comment: Thank you very much if I already have the textboxes inside the movieclip can I do it with out adding the textboxes as children or should I just take the boxes out of the movie clip and add them from as3

Comment: my personal preference is to do as much with code as possible (all :))